# WPF Mahapps Hamburger Menu open User Control with extended constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I'm using exactly this Hamburger menu example
https://jkarger.de/2017/02/06/mahapps-hamburgermenu/

This works fine as long the views have the default constructor.
However I need to pass an object from the MetroWindow, where the Hamburger menu is implemented, to a UserControl called by clicking a menu item.

The XAML code for the menu item is like this.

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
    <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Home">
            <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                <views:main />
            </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

        <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Private">
            <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                <views:private />
            </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>

        <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph="" Label="Settings">
            <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                <views:settings />
            </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
    </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
</controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
```

For instance the "main" view.

```
 <controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                <views:main />
 </controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
```

This is the constructor of my "main" UserControl.

```
#region PUBLIC_PROPERTIES
TesterConfig.TesterConfig tc;
#endregion
public main(TesterConfig.TesterConfig configuration)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tc = configuration;
}
```

XAML for the "main" UserControl"

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestsystemConfiguration.Views.main"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestsystemConfiguration.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="423*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="imageLogo" Grid.Column="2" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/logo.png" Margin="5" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbWorkingStation" IsEnabled="False"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,2,10,2" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="cbWorkingStation_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnOpenDocs" Content="Doku öffnen" Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Grid.Row="7" Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Upper"/>
        <Label Content="Arbeitsplatz:" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The "TesterConfig" is an object in my project and declared in the parent MetroWindow. How can I pass the reference to the UserControl?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't create an instance of a view in the XAML like this unless the view has a parameterless constructor: `<views:main />`. This is not supported. Set the `Tag` property programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @mm8.
According to your suggestions I did it this way.

XAML (MenuItem)

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem Glyph=""
                        Label="Home"
                        Tag="main">
</Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
```

C# Code:

```
    private void MenuControl_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        HamburgerMenuGlyphItem i = e.ClickedItem as HamburgerMenuGlyphItem;
        if(i != null)
        {
            UserControl uc = new UserControl();
            switch(i.Tag.ToString())
            {
                case "main":
                    uc = new Views.main(tc);
                    break;

                case "testsystems":
                    uc = new Views.testsystems();
                    break;
            }
            i.Tag = uc;
            this.MenuControl.Content = i;
        }
    }
```

I created a switch depending on the tag.
Thanks for your help!

Best,
Andy

Comment: How did you bind the event MenuControl_ItemClick to the HamburgerMenuGlyphItem?