# Set the data context of a custom control of mahapps hamburger menu tag

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

I have come across lots of questions regarding this topic, however, I haven't found one that would solve my problem. For example, I can't use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747819/wpf-mahapps-hamburger-menu-open-user-control-with-extended-constructor) solution since I'm using MVVM and I register my view models with the help of the host builder. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293523/mahapps-metro-hamburgermenu-binding-not-working) question sets a view model's property to a text block's text property with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494226/cannot-find-source-for-binding-with-reference-relativesource-findancestor) one. I have been trying to use the Binding Proxy but couldn't get it to work.

To be more specific, I use MVVM and so I don't have default constructors. I set my view's data context in my **App.xaml** like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>

           ..

          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
                <views:HomeView />
          </DataTemplate>

          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:LogoutViewModel}">
               <views:LogoutView />
          </DataTemplate>

     </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

My user control on which I have the hamburger menu looks like this:

**HamburgerMenuRipple.xaml**

```
<mah:HamburgerMenu
        x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
        DisplayMode="CompactInline"
        HamburgerButtonClick="HamburgerMenuControl_HamburgerButtonClick"
        IsPaneOpen="True"
        ItemInvoked="HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
        OpenPaneLength="275"
        OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.HamburgerMenu.Ripple}"
        VerticalScrollBarOnLeftSide="False">

        <!--  Header  -->
        <mah:HamburgerMenu.HamburgerMenuHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Padding="10,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="16"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="White"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </mah:HamburgerMenu.HamburgerMenuHeaderTemplate>


        <!--  Items  -->
        <mah:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>

            <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Home}" Label="Home" />

                <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Bell}" Label="Notifications" />

                ..

            </mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        </mah:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>

        <!--  Options  -->
        <mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
            <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <mah:HamburgerMenuSeparatorItem x:Name="Separator_2" IsVisible="{Binding ElementName=Separator_2}" />

                <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Cog}" Label="Settings" />

                <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Logout}" Label="Logout">
                    <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                        <views:LogoutView/> <!--How can I set the datacontext here?-->
                    </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem>

            </mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        </mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>

        <mah:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem}">
                <Grid Margin="20,0,10,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Margin="0,15,0,5"
                        Padding="0"
                        FontFamily="{DynamicResource MahApps.Fonts.Family.Header}"
                        FontSize="16"
                        Text="{Binding Label}" />
                    <ScrollViewer
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Focusable="False"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Tag}" Focusable="False" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </mah:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>
    </mah:HamburgerMenu>
```

My Logout view is simple for now, but it looks like this:

**LogoutView.xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Do you want to log out?" />
        <Button Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" Content="Log out" />
    </StackPanel>
```

And the view model:

**LogoutViewModel.cs**

```
    public class LogoutViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public ICommand LogoutCommand { get; }
    
            public LogoutViewModel(IAuthenticationService authenticationService, INavigationService loginNavigationService)
            {
                LogoutCommand = new LogoutCommand(this, authenticationService, loginNavigationService);
            }
        }
```

**AddViewModelsHostBuilderExtensions.cs**

```
 public static IHostBuilder AddViewModels(this IHostBuilder host)
        {
            host.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();

                services.AddSingleton<CreateViewModel<LoginViewModel>>(services => () => CreateLoginViewModel(services));
                services.AddSingleton<CreateViewModel<HomeViewModel>>(services => () => CreateHomeViewModel(services));
                services.AddSingleton<CreateViewModel<LogoutViewModel>>(services => () => CreateLogoutViewModel(services));
            });

            return host;
        }

        private static LoginViewModel CreateLoginViewModel(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return new LoginViewModel(
                services.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<HomeViewModel>>());
        }

        private static HomeViewModel CreateHomeViewModel(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return new HomeViewModel();
        }

        private static LogoutViewModel CreateLogoutViewModel(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            return new LogoutViewModel(
                services.GetRequiredService<NavigationService<LoginViewModel>>());
        }
```

My view appears correctly when I click the 'Log out' item, however, whenever I click on the 'Log out' button, the command doesn't fire. Is it because the view doesn't have the view model's data context (according to the other questions)? Or did I make a mistake somewhere else? How do I set the data context of the view in this situation?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code. It might be helpful to see it running. Assuming it's not proprietary, can you host your code on GitHub or somewhere like it?

Comment: @drazse: How and where are you instantiating your `LogoutViewModel`...?

Comment: @mm8 Dan Stevens asked me to upload it to github and so I did. Like I said, I do it in my host builder with a delegate but I don't know how to bind it to my view in this case as binding it in App.xaml doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You somehow need to set the `DataContext` of your view to an instance of your view model? Where are you trying to do this?

Comment: It's in App.xaml when I set the DataTemplate. I don't know any other way of doing this. May you show how to do it in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, @mm8 's comment helped me to start working in the right direction, and then I could figure out the rest by myself, so I post my solution here, hope it might help others in the future.

Basically, what I did was that I created a view model property in my HomeViewModel. I guess you can create it in this property, but I register view models in my host builder so I get it from my constructor.

**HomeViewModel.cs**

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public LogoutViewModel LogoutViewModel { get; }

        public HomeViewModel(LogoutViewModel logoutViewModel)
        {
            LogoutViewModel = logoutViewModel;
        }
    }
```

After this, I created a dependency property in my hamburger menu user control so that I can pass the view model from the HomeViewModel to the hamburger menu user control.

**HomeView.xaml**

```
..
<controls:HamburgerMenuRipple LogoutViewDataContext="{Binding LogoutViewModel}" />
..
```

**HamburgerMenuRipple.xaml.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LogoutViewDataContextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LogoutViewDataContext), typeof(LogoutViewModel), typeof(HamburgerMenuRipple), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public LogoutViewModel LogoutViewDataContext
        {
            get { return (LogoutViewModel)GetValue(LogoutViewDataContextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LogoutViewDataContextProperty, value); }
        }
```

And then I set the data context of the tag's user control with the help of the OnItemInvoked command.

```
private void HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked(object sender, HamburgerMenuItemInvokedEventArgs e)
        {
            HamburgerMenuControl.Content = e.InvokedItem;
            var iconItemTag = (e.InvokedItem as HamburgerMenuIconItem).Tag;

            if (iconItemTag != null)
            {
                switch(iconItemTag)
                {
                    case LogoutView:
                        ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
                        (iconItemTag as UserControl).DataContext = LogoutViewDataContext;
                        break;

                    default:
                        ErrorMessage = "No data context has been bound to this view.";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**HamburgerMenuRipple.xaml**

```
<mah:HamburgerMenu
            x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
            DisplayMode="CompactInline"
            IsPaneOpen="True"
            ItemInvoked="HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked"

..

<mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
                <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                    <mah:HamburgerMenuSeparatorItem />

                    <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem
                        x:Name="LogoutIconItem"
                        Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Logout}"
                        Label="Logout">
                        <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                            <views:LogoutView HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem>

                </mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            </mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>

..
```